# manutenção off-line dos módulos Python

Tags: python

Devido a problemas com internet onde estou morando, preciso manter os pacotes e instalar novos sem a conexão com a internet, mantendo um microservidor montado em NanoPi para que nele eu obtenha os arquivos.

Qual ferramenta e procedimento devo adotar para manter e instalar tais módulos do Python?

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução é utilizar a ferramenta `minirepo` que permite fazer download de pacotes Python do [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) sem internet.

---

A maneira mais fácil de instalá-lo é usar o `pip`:

```
$ pip install minirepo
```

---

Ou faça o download do arquivo do pacote em https://pypi.python.org/pypi/minirepo em seguida:

```
$ tar xvzf minirepo-1.0.3.tar.gz
$ cd minirepo-1.0.3
$ python setup.py install
```

---

Você também pode usar o `git`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sganis/minirepo.git
$ cd minirepo
$ python setup.py install
```

---

A [documentação](https://pypi.org/project/minirepo/) de uso é simples.